# Find the current memory setting for dom0 - XenServer 6.5

Tags: xenserver

On XenServer 6.5, I could find how to set the memory settings but I couldn't find how to read the current setting (what's the min, what's the max values) from the command line or by looking into a file.

Some posts on-line refers to /etc/default/grub file but that is for an older version of XenServer.

Comment: Check the kernel command line.  In a generic sense it's used to be set there.  i.e. cat /proc/cmdline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also run `/opt/xensource/libexec/xen-cmdline --get-xen dom0_mem`

eg:
`/opt/xensource/libexec/xen-cmdline --get-xen dom0_mem
dom0_mem=4096M,max:4096M`

Answer (score 2):

I just found my answer... `/boot/extlinux.conf` has the start up parameters.